# Javascript - Trouble using for...in to iterate through an object

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I have a dynamically-generated object that looks like this:

```
colorArray = { 
    AR: "#8BBDE1", 
    AU: "#135D9E", 
    AT: "#8BBDE1",
    ... }
```

I'm trying to use it to color a map by using [this plugin](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/) and the 'colors' attribute during the call to the plugin.  Like this:

```
$('#iniDensityMap').vectorMap({
    backgroundColor: '#c2e2f2',
    colors: colorArray,
    ... (some other params)
});
```

But it doesn't color in the countries. When I hard code this in, it works fine - but it must be dynamically generated for this project, so something like this won't work for me (although it does in fact color the map):

```
$('#iniDensityMap').vectorMap({
    backgroundColor: '#c2e2f2',
    colors: { AR: "#8BBDE1", AU: "#135D9E", AT: "#8BBDE1" },
    ... (some other params)
});
```

I've traced the issue far enough into the plugin to find it has something to do with this loop:

```
setColors: function(key, color) {
  if (typeof key == 'string') {
    this.countries[key].setFill(color);
  } else {

    var colors = key; //This is the parameter passed through to the plugin

    for (var code in colors) {

      //THIS WILL NOT GET CALLED

      if (this.countries[code]) {
        this.countries[code].setFill(colors[code]);
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I've also tried iterating through the `colorArray` object on my own, outside of the plugin and I'm running into the same issue.  Whatever sits inside the **for ( var x in obj )** isn't firing.  I've also noticed that `colorArray.length` returns *undefined*.  Another important note is that I've instantiated `var colorArray = {};` in a separate  call, attempting to ensure that it is sitting at the global scope and able to be manipulated.

I'm thinking that the problem is either:

1. The way I'm dynamically populating the object - `colorArray[cCode] =
   cColor;` (in a jQuery .each call)
2. I'm once again confusing the differences between Arrays() and Objects() in javascript
3. It is a scope issue perhaps?
4. Some combination of everything above.

**EDIT #1:** I've moved my additional question about Objects in the Console in Firebug to a new post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763932/objects-in-firebug-console).  That question deals more specifically with Firebug than the underlying JS problem I'm asking about here.

**Edit #2: Additional info**
Here's the code I'm using to dynamically populate the Object:

```
function parseDensityMapXML() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "media/XML/mapCountryData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("Country").each(function () {
            var cName = $(this).find("Name").text();
            var cIniCount = $(this).find("InitiativeCount").text();
            var cUrl = $(this).find("SearchURL").text();
            var cCode = $(this).find("CountryCode").text();

            //Populate the JS Object
            iniDensityData[cCode] = { "initiatives": cIniCount, "url": cUrl, "name": cName };
            //set colors according to values of initiatives count
            colorArray[cCode] = getCountryColor(cIniCount);
        });
    }
});
} //end function parseDensityMapXML();
```

This function is then called on a click event of a checkbox elsewhere on the page.  The Objects `iniDensityData` and `colorArray` are declared in the head of the html file - hoping that keeps them in global scope:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Initialize a bunch of variables in the global scope
    iniDensityData = {};
    colorArray = {};
</script>
```

And finally, here's a snippet from the XML file that is being read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<icapCountryData>
  <Country>
    <Name>Albania</Name>
    <CountryCode>AL</CountryCode>
    <InitiativeCount>7</InitiativeCount>
    <SearchURL>~/advance_search.aspx?search=6</SearchURL>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <Name>Argentina</Name>
    <CountryCode>AR</CountryCode>
    <InitiativeCount>15</InitiativeCount>
    <SearchURL>~/advance_search.aspx?search=11</SearchURL>
  </Country>
  ... and so on ...
</icapCountryData>
```

Comment: you are definitely confusing [] and {}, at least.  {} doesn't have a length property unless you explicitly add one.

Comment: also: when you set a breakpoint on your for loop, is the value of colors what you expect it to be?

Comment: Just taking a shot in the dark, here...you mention that you're using the `jQuery.each` function. Are you by chance using the `this` keyword inside of that function? e.g. `this.countries`? `this` being improperly bound is one of the most common causes of errors in JavaScript.

Comment: @DanDaviesBrackett yeah, I'm pretty sure I want to use {} (Object, correct?) and that .length won't work for that - but certainly the for/in loop should?

Comment: @HerroRygar Pretty sure that's done correctly, in the success callback of a jQuery ajax call, I'm doing this: 
`$(xml).find("Country").each(function () { 
   var cCode = $(this).find("CountryCode").text(); 
   ...some more stuff }`
 and then populating the **colorArray** like this:
`colorArray[cCode] = cColor;`

Comment: What about the `colorArray` variable (in truth, it's actually an object though)? What about the scope of that? It would help quite a bit if you would post more code to get the full context. Using developer tools may also help you dig deeper; place the following statement right before calling the `vectorMap` function: `console.log(colorArray);`. This will write out to your browser's debug console the contents of the `colorArray` object. Google instructions on how to pull up the console. My guess is that this object is going to be either `{}`,`null`, or `undefined`.

Comment: ...but yeah, if you could post the entire code block in question, that would make it much easier to diagnose a scope issue.

Comment: You might consider not calling an `Object` an `Array`. An array in javascript uses square brackets `var arr = [];`. Calling it an array makes us think you're confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved it!** Originally, I was calling the function `parseDensityMapXML()` and then immediately after it calling another function `loadDensityMapXML()` which took the object created dynamically in the first function and iterated through it.  Problem was, it wasn't called as a **callback** from the first function, so was firing before the Object had even been built.

To fix, I just amended the first function mentioned above to call the second function *after* the **.each()** was finished creating the objects:

```
function parseDensityMapXML() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "media/XML/mapCountryData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("Country").each(function () {
            var cName = $(this).find("Name").text();
            var cIniCount = $(this).find("InitiativeCount").text();
            var cUrl = $(this).find("SearchURL").text();
            var cCode = $(this).find("CountryCode").text();

            //Populate the JS Object
            iniDensityData[cCode] = { "initiatives": cIniCount, "url": cUrl, "name": cName };
            //set colors according to values of initiatives count
            colorArray[cCode] = getCountryColor(cIniCount);
        });

        /* and then call the jVectorMap plugin - this MUST be done as a callback
           after the above parsing.  If called separately, it will fire before the
           objects iniDensityData and colorArray are created! */
        loadDensityMapXML();
    }
});
} //end function parseDensityMapXML();
```