# Objects in Firebug console

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

This is an extension of a question I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750145/javascript-trouble-using-for-in-to-iterate-through-an-object).

I'm having trouble manipulating js Objects, and I think it has something to do with **scope** or how the Objects are populated.  I'm trying to use Firebug to get to the bottom of the issue, and did find one discrepancy that I can't explain.  **Does anyone know why sometimes Console will show an object like this**:
[image]

*Where it shows the contents of the Object*

**And sometimes like this:**

[image]

*Where it looks as if the Object is empty*

However, the object **isn't empty** - when I click on the **Object { }** in the above screenshot, I'm taken to the DOM inspector, which sure enough shows the contents of that object:
[image]

Needless to say, it works the first way (in which I hard-coded the object's keys/values) but not the second way (in which they are dynamically added). I'm thinking if I can figure out why Console displays these two seemingly similar Objects differently, I may be able to get the bottom of the problem in my code.  And I apologize if asking a similar question twice is bad form, but I figured this is a Firebug-specific question and the other is javascript related...

Comment: ...you've mentioned in both questions that things work when you hard-code values, but doesn't work when the object is populated dynamically. But in neither question did you show the code that you're using to populate the object. I'm guessing you're making an asynchronous AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks @amnotiam I've added some additional snippets to the first question.  Can't really post all of the code as it is confidential client work, but I'm putting up what I can...

Comment: So you're probably calling `parseDensityMapXML()`, and then trying to use the `colorArray` immediately after that call, right?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**  Really quite simple in retrospect, and I think @amnotiam was on to the right track with his last comment. What is happening is that I'm calling `console.log()` *after* the Object is created, but *before* any values have been added.  By the time I click on it to inspect it in the DOM, all the values have been added.

More details on the answer to original post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750145/javascript-trouble-using-for-in-to-iterate-through-an-object).